# "transition: transform" doesn't work in desktop browsers

Tags: css

I use this transition css3:

```
-webkit-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
-moz-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
-o-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
-ms-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
 transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
```

they work fine on mobile browser (firefox app, chrome app, safari with iphone 9.2)

but doesn't work on desktop browsers (ff, chrome ecc).. how is possible ?

**EDIT**

I created an example with jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9s3q34z/

i have an element with that css3 (transition), then with an event i add `transform: rotate(-180deg)`. In this way i can to rotate the element (it will be an animation). I tried this code in local, in jsfiddle and works fine. But when i tried this code in my website i have problems with desktop browser (except safari).

In my website i have css stylesheet and inside i have also media query (`@media (min-width: 1025px)` and `@media (max-width: 1024px)`) but that css3 (transition) **are not inside in media query**.

With firebug i analyzed the element and don'have the css that i showed you (and i don't understand why).

But with mobile browser (i mean app mobile not window of desktop browser resized) works very well.

Comment: define "doesn't work" - presumably you are applying a transform? Is the transform being triggered by an event or is it present from the start? Is the transform working with no transition, or is the transform itself not working? Do you have any media-queries in your CSS that could be causing the difference (quick related tests - does the transition work if you make your window very narrow? What about if you use e.g. chrome's mobile emulation mode?)

Comment: Hm, it works: https://fiddle.jshell.net/oLqs3L6d/ An example would be great.

Comment: 2 min that i create a jsfiddle

Comment: you can add a snippet inline in the question editor - better than relying on external sites

Comment: I don't know add a snippet inline one moment please

Comment: EDIT :)  I hope you can help me

Comment: @CupawnTae please see edit

Comment: @RwamDev please see edit

Comment: for future reference, the button in the toolbar with `<>` on it inserts a snippet - you can edit it a bit like jsfiddle, but it goes right in the question. Could something inside your media query be overriding the CSS? Another thing that could cause it would be a parse error in the css. Look at what's directly before the selector for the CSS in question - is the previous block correctly closed with a `}`? Is there a stray semicolon, or a "comment" starting with `//` instead of `/*..*/` - that type of thing. Maybe move this CSS up to the top of the file and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: I tried all you suggest but nothing (doesn't work with desktop browser Firefox and Chrome)... Maybe the cause is the minification of css? Read other my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876569/transition-delay-in-transition-shorthand?noredirect=1#comment59417028_35876569

Comment: unlikely - CSS minifiers would be broken if they changed behaviour. And as I just commented on your other question, the delay property is optional, so removed it doesn't cause an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the **css minification**, infact after minification css showed in first post becomes:

```
-webkit-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0;
-moz-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0;
-o-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0;
-ms-transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0;
 transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0;
```

**transition-delay** dont'have the unit (`s` for second), and for firefox is a problem so not read its css (i think that for same reason doesn't work on Chrome). 
 So to fix this we can write a *transition shorhand* without `transition-delay`:

```
 -webkit-transition: transform 250ms ease-out;
 -moz-transition: transform 250ms ease-out;
 -o-transition: transform 250ms ease-out;
 -ms-transition: transform 250ms ease-out;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-out;
```

Infact now works very well in each browser (desktop or mobile). I hope that this answer can help other users. Thanks a lot and sorry for my english ;D