# Transition-delay in transition shorthand?

Tags: css

In CSS transition shorthand is essential transition-delay? I would like to know if is possible to use shorthand without transition-delay...
Because i have a module on my website that minimize ces and i read that minification delete units to `transition delay`, and if is without unit transition doesn't work with firefox (for me also with chrome).. So:
So can i write in this way:

```
  transition: font-size 2s ease-out; //without 0s of transition delay
```

Is possible ???

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Comment: I guess you use moz- in css, no?

Comment: @Oscar LT yes use also that option (with prefix) but nothing. Can you answer :) ?

Comment: I always use this web and I don't see difference between firefox and chrome: http://www.css3maker.com/. Sorry!

Comment: You don't say me if i can use shorthand transition without transition-delay????

Comment: I want to tell you that I use your code in that web and works, try it you.

Comment: yes, it's optional, and defaults to `0s`